# Webapp without a framework on pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

Is it possible for me to write my own server and use that on pythonanywhere? I saw in the wsgi file that it just imports app as application from my source. Can I just supply an object called app that will behave in ways it expects? Where would I find all the info I need to make my own socket server work on pythonanywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  PythonAnywhere only supports WSGI applications, so you wouldn't be able to build your own socket server.   But you could build an application that implements the WSGI protocol, without using any third party framework...

[Here](http://pythonpaste.org/do-it-yourself-framework.html)'s an example of that last...